# DB2 9.7 LUW - How do I SET SESSION_USER when I am DBADM,SECADM?

Tags: security, db2, best-practices

Based on a [previous question I have asked](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/how-to-revoke-dbadm-and-clean-up-any-related-objects-from-db2-luw), I am attempting to work on a solution as recommended by mustaccio's answer, whereby I have another ID to create my DDL objects.

I have been trying to follow an IBM developer works article called ["DB2 security, Part 8: Twelve DB2 security best practices"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0607wasserman/index.html) in my attempt to do it. I have noticed it appears the article was written for DB2 8.2 at the time. I am currently working on DB2 9.7 fix pack 4 ESE for LUW. Specifically I am on AIX. I am currently testing out how to do this on my local system, which is Windowx XP SP3 and using DB2 9.7 fix pack 4 Express-C for LUW.

I have my local user account (which is the instance owner) called db2admin in this case (not so on our AIX systems). This ID belongs to the DB2ADMNS group. Since it is different from my Windows account I make sure I attach to the instance first and then create my database to assure that db2admin is granted `DBADM`,`SECADM`,`DATAACCESS`,`ACCESSCTRL` on my database.

```
db2 attach to DB2 user db2admin using ********
db2 create database SECTEST automatic storage yes on 'C:\' dbpath on 'C:\'
  using codeset UTF-8 territory US collate using system
```

After that I connect to the system as db2admin

```
db2 connect to sectest user db2admin using ********
```

Then to test things out, I made sure I granted `CONNECT` and `SECADM` to my Windows account

```
db2 grant connect,secadm on database to user myid
```

And then I wished to set up my bogus ID to create objects under. I intentionally create this ID as nine characters to help with preventing connection to DB2 from the command line, but still allow it via `SET SESSION_USER`. For the sake of simplicity I have named my ID bobabob97.

So I have done the following:

```
db2 grant CREATETAB,IMPLICIT_SCHEMA,BINDADD,CREATE_NOT_FENCED_ROUTINE,
  CREATE_EXTERNAL_ROUTINE on database to user bobabob97
db2 grant use of tablespace userspace1 to user bobabob97
```

At this point I think I have everything set up correctly. I have explicitly ***not*** granted bobabob97 `CONNECT` on the database as I do not want anyone to be able to connect to the database with this ID.

So now I try to switch over to that ID to create test creating my objects and owning them under a generic ID.

```
db2 set session_user=bobabob97
```

But then I get the following error:

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
>   not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it
>   returned: SQL0552N  "DB2ADMIN" does not have the privilege to perform
>   operation "SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION".  SQLSTATE=28000

So, now I am puzzled. The ID I am currently connected to the database as (db2admin) has `DBADM`,`SECADM`,`DATAACCESS`,and `ACCESSCTRL` on the database (and of course it implicitly holds `CONNECT`,`CREATETAB`,`BINDADD`,`QUIESCE_CONNECT`,`IMPLICIT_SCHEMA`,`LOAD`,`CREATE_NOT_FENCED_ROUTINE`, and `CREATE_EXTERNAL_ROUTINE`). I am essentially "god" on the database. Why can I not switch to this ID?

I tried playing with `GRANT SETSESSIONUSER`, but I know `SECADM` can't grant to itself. What do I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I actually figured out how to handle this. I needed to grant the ability for my `DBADM`,`SECADM` to transfer to any ID through the group not the specific ID. In this way I get around the `SECADM` restrictions.

```
db2 grant setsessionuser on public to group DB2ADMNS
```

Since my ID db2admin is in this group, it can now switch to any ID (the public part). If I only wanted to be able to switch to that ID, I could have used:

```
db2 grant setsessionuser on user bobabob97 to group DB2ADMNS
```

So now I can perform

```
db2 set session_user=bobabob97
```

and it works.

To switch back I only need to run

```
db2 set session_user=system_user
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, I can run a SET SCHEMA due to having bobabob97 been granted IMPLICIT_SCHEMA, but I cannot do a CREATE_SCHEMA. I would like to find out how to do the CREATE_SCHEMA (even using the AUTHORIZATION clause doesn't help) as any schemas created implicitly are technically owned by PUBLIC and I'd rather not have things owned by PUBLIC.

Comment: CREATE SCHEMA requires DBADM, as evident from the manual. I'm assuming you're getting this error while connected with your "DDL owner" user, as the other user has DBADM.

Comment: @mustaccio - I was wondering about that. So I probably need to grant DBADM WITHOUT DATAACCESS WITHOUT ACCESSCTRL? I realize I will implicitly have SELECT via having CONTROL on the objects. I suppose I would then have to revoke QUIESCE_CONNECT, CONNECT, and LOAD?

Comment: @mustaccio - or is it better to have implicit schemas even if those are owned by PUBLIC? Also curious, if you have a RESTRICTIVE database, are implicit schemas still owned by PUBLIC?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have all the answers, so you'll just have to test by yourself. You seem to have a more thorough approach than most organizations I've worked with: in most cases the intended object owner/schema creator is just granted DBADM, or rather whoever has DBADM creates all objects. And I think SYSIBM, not PUBLIC is the owner of implicit schemas. PUBLIC is basically a group, so it can't be the owner of anything.

Comment: @mustaccio - Fair enough. :) Can't fault me for asking though. I think you may be right about the SYSIBM thing, now that I think about it. I think maybe PUBLIC is just granted access by default. I'll have to reread that spot in Information Center again.